# Removing entries from a file by matching a column with a column from another file

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, gawk

I have two files f1.txt and f2.txt. I want to able to take remove rows within File 1 (f1.txt) if its first column has a matching entry in File2 (f2.txt). f2 has only 1 column per line where as each row of f.txt will have two or more columns. Here is an example:

cat f1.txt

```
1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 1000
2, 100, 200, 300, 400
3, 100, 2000, 3000
4, 400, 500 
5, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000
```

cat f2. txt

```
2
4
```

Here is the desired output:

```
1, 10, 20, 30, 40
3, 100, 2000, 3000, 400
5, 500, 600, 700, 800
```

Comment: read the column from f2.txt into a set, then for each line in f1.txt, split out the first column and see if its in the set. we don't write your code, just suggest how to improve it.

Comment: Where did the 6th and subsequent fields from lines 1 and 5 go? Where did the `400` at the end of line 3 come from? Put just a TINY bit of effort into asking the question.

Comment: Try this: `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {p=1;c=+$1;for (i in a) if(c==i) p=0} p' f2.txt f1.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Modify the pattern file f2.txt, as so :

```
sed -i -e 's/^/\^/;s/$/\\b/' file1
```

f2.txt will look like

```
^2\b
^4\b
etc.
```

Then compare the files with grep:

```
grep -vf f2.txt f1.txt
```

Comment: Any time you write a shell loop to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Also - what do you think will happen given your solution if f2.txt has a line with a 1 in it and f1.txt has a line that starts with, say, 10?

Comment: @Ed Morton You're right I forgot the comma, assuming that the numbers are separated by commas. What would you suggest would be a better approach, using awk?.

Comment: yes, awk is the tool that the guys who invented shell invented for shell to call to manipulate text. The whole script can be done concisely, efficiently, and robustly as just `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a)' f2.txt f1.txt`

Comment: @EdMorton check my edit, do you approve? It works fine if f2.txt is a single column, as OP stated.

Comment: I initially said "Looks good to me." but now I realise it'll match on any field, not just the first field, so it won't work.

Comment: @EdMorton OK, I'm sure my new solution works...its the best I can do without copying the awk solution you provided.